# Kotlin recursion stack overflow

Tags: recursion, kotlin, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I have written this recursive function in Kotlin:

```
fun recursive(target: String, population: Population, debugFun: (String) -> Unit) : Population {
    if (population.solution(target).toString() == target) {
        return population
    }
    debugFun.invoke(population.solution(target).toString())
    return recursive(target, population.evolve(target), debugFun)
}
```

It will run an indeterminate amount of times (because I'm using randomness to converge on solution in evolutionary algorithm). I am frequently getting stack overflow. What is the maximum stack depth for Kotlin/JVM languages? Should i just write the function non recursively?

Comment: Or should I write it in such a way that the recursive call is made on the tailing line of the function to allow the compiler to optimize with tail recursion? I don't fully understand how the compiler optimizes for tail recursion.

Comment: I've edited the question to use tail recursion as the same problem still occurs!

Comment: Koltin compiler does not optimize for tail recursion (yet). You can use extension functions on collections instead of recursion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *tailrec* keyword tells the Kotlin compiler to use tail recursion. It therefore unrolls the recursion into a loop and this way you get rid of the *StackOverflowError*.

```
tailrec fun recursive(target: String, population: Population, debugFun: (String) -> Unit) : Population {
    if (population.solution(target).toString() == target) {
        return population
    }
    debugFun.invoke(population.solution(target).toString())
    return recursive(target, population.evolve(target), debugFun)
}
```

So when using *tailrec* the compiler creates something which matches to following function:

```
fun recursive(target: String, population: Population, debugFun: (String) -> Unit) : Population{
    var tmp = population

    while (true) {
        if (tmp.solution(target).toString() == target) {
            return tmp
        }
        debugFun.invoke(population.solution(target).toString())
        tmp = tmp.evolve(target)
    }
}
```

In this function no method calls are made any more therefore nothing gets pushed to the stack and we are save from *StackOverflowError*.

Note that we can still run into an endless loop!

Comment: @ThomasCook see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion for a detailed description of how tail recursion works

Comment: Added a version of the function without recursion to show how the compiler converts the recursion into a loop